# Dialog does not open when called shortly after being dismissed

Tags: android, dialog, showdialog

In my app, the user logs in with a custom made login dialog. The user can confirm and exit the dialog in two ways:

1. Press the Enter/Done button in the password box.
2. Press the OK button.

When the user has confirmed, the provided credentials are verified. If the credentials were incorrect, the dialog will reappear. This does only work if the user presses the Enter/Done button in the password box and not if the OK button is pressed. I use the same code for both the `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` and the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. I've tried debugging the code and I've discovered that in both cases, the `boolean android.app.Activity.showDialog(int id, Bundle args)` return `true`, which tells if the dialog was displayed or not.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to show a dialog again after it's been dismissed. It probably is, but have you considered creating a new dialog?

Comment: The thing is that it is possible and it is reopened when called from the OnEditorActionListener, but not from the OnClickListener. And I want to display the same dialog to notify the user that the provided credentials were uncorrect and that he has to enter new credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your best bet is to just create a new dialog. Should'nt be to hard.

UPDATE:

Also you could set it to

```
setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And then when you want it to be show again

```
 View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: I tried to manually create and show the display instead of calling showDialog and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just `hide()` it? Only `dismiss()` it when you are really done with the `Dialog`

Comment: Good idea. I didn't know about that method. Still, the onClick method always dismisses the dialog.

Comment: I believe that if you are using a custom Dialog, then you can override everything, choose whether to `hide()` and `dismiss()`. You can try override the onClick method, have a boolean `isFinish` to check the status of the procedure